# Grab SearchEngine results as much as possible for a survey

Tags: php, search, search-engine

For a survey I am trying to grab google search result from my php page. I grab six results then i click next button to get next page records.but after 9 pages e.g. 64 results it gives following error:

```
stdClass Object
(
[responseData] => 
[responseDetails] => out of range start
[responseStatus] => 400
)
```

I just want as much data as possible. i dont mind if it is google search engine or any other search engine. but for accurate result of survey I want large number of resultset. Can anybody knows how can i do that ?

Is it possible to grab results through cron ? Is there any other way ?

Comment: What are you searching for? So we can see how other sites might help

Comment: any keyword like sites related online exam or such..

Comment: Can you share some stuff

Comment: I have used google customsearch api for that. even you can let me know any other option too.

Comment: Share your code. Then we can try to help you

Comment: @nl-x I had used google search api using searchControl.addSearcher(new google.search.WebSearch()). now i am using the following code added by  Hugo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ATTENTION**

Google tries to prevent scraping and so servers will be blocked and requests will be dropped when they suspect scraping. So you can use this if you occassionally need to get some google results.
Check [google-scraper.squabbel.com](http://google-scraper.squabbel.com/) for a proxy based scraper and more information on googles blocking mechanism. Its also against their policy and thus illigal.

---

The google api will not allow for more then 64 results, so if you need more you need to scrape the site yourself. As it was a fun project, I have created a class to do this for you.

It requires the free [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) so you need download this code aswell.

it will output an array like

```
array(100) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(67) "Online Tests - Online aptitude tests for interview, competitive ..."
    ["href"]=>
    string(36) "http://www.indiabix.com/online-test/"
    ["description"]=>
    string(168) "Online aptitude tests for competitive examination, entrance examination and 
    campus interview. Take various tests and find out how much you score before 
    you ... "
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["title"]=>
    string(37) "Test your English - Cambridge English"
    ["href"]=>
    string(50) "http://www.cambridgeenglish.org/test-your-english/"
    ["description"]=>
    string(179) "Test Your English. This is a quick, free online test. It will tell you which Cambridge 
    English exam may be best for you. Click 'Begin Test' and answer each of the ... "
  }

  //removed for better visibility

}
```

How to use:

```
//start the scraper for google.com (english results)
$gs = new GoogleScraper();

//start the scraper for google.nl (dutch results)
//$gs = new GoogleScraper('https://www.google.nl');

//set your search query
$gs->SearchQuery('online exams');

//start loading the pages. You can enter any integer above 0
$gs->LoadPages(10);

//dump the results, but its just an array so you can also do other things with it.  
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($gs->GetResults());
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

And then the `GoogleScraper.php`

```
<?php
require_once('simple_html_dom.php');
class GoogleScraper
{
  private $_results;
  private $_baseUrl;
  private $_searchQuery;
  private $_resultsPerPage;

  /**
   *  constructor
   *  I use the constructor to set all the defaults to keep it all in one place
   */
  final public function __construct($baseUrl='')
  {
    $this->_results = array();
    $this->_resultsPerPage = 100;

    if (empty($baseUrl)) {
      $this->_baseUrl = 'https://www.google.com';
    } else {
      $this->_baseUrl = $baseUrl;
    }
  }

  /**
   *  cleanup
   */
  final public function __destruct()
  {
    unset($this->_results);
    unset($this->_baseUrl);
    unset($this->_searchQuery);
  }

  /**
   *  Set the query
   */
  final public function SearchQuery($searchQuery)
  {
    if (!(is_string($searchQuery) || is_numeric($searchQuery)))
    {
      throw new Exception('Invalid query type');      
    }

    $this->_searchQuery = $searchQuery;
  }

  /**
   *  Set the number of results per page
   */
  final public function ResultsPerPage($resultsPerPage)
  {
    if (!is_int($resultsPerPage) || $resultsPerPage<10 || $resultsPerPage>100)
    {
      throw new Exception('Results per page must be value between 10 and 100');      
    }

    $this->_resultsPerPage = $resultsPerPage;
  }

  /**
   *  Get the result
   */
  final public function GetResults()
  {
    return $this->_results;
  }


  /**
   *  Scrape the search results
   */
  final public function LoadPages($pages=1)
  {
    if (!is_int($pages) || $pages<1)
    {
      throw new Exception('Invalid number of pages');      
    }
    if (empty($this->_searchQuery))
    {
      throw new Exception('Missing search query');      
    }

    $url = $this->_baseUrl . '/search?num='.$this->_resultsPerPage.'&q=' . urlencode($this->_searchQuery);
    $currentPage = 1;
    while($pages--) {
      if ($content = $this->LoadUrl($url)) {
        /*
        Load content in to simple html dom
        */    
        $html = new simple_html_dom();
        $html->load($content);

        /*
        Find and handle search results
        */  
        $items = $html->find('div#ires li');
        foreach($items as $item) {
          /*
          Only normal search results have this container. Special results like found images or news dont have it.
          */  
          $check = $item->find('div.s');
          if (count($check)!=1) {
            continue;
          }

          $head = $item->find('h3.r a', 0);
          $result['title'] = $head->plaintext;

          /*
          If we dont have a title, there is no point in continuing
          */  
          if (empty($result['title'])) {
            continue;
          }

          $result['href'] = $head->href;

          /*
          Check if we can parse the URL for the actual url
          */  
          if (!empty($result['href'])) {
            $qs = explode('?', $result['href']);
            if (!empty($qs[1])) {
              parse_str($qs[1], $querystring);
              if (!empty($querystring['q'])) {
                $result['href'] = $querystring['q'];
              }
            }
          }

          /*
          Try to find the description
          */  
          $info = $item->find('span.st', 0);
          $result['description'] = $info->plaintext;

          /*
          Add the results to the total
          */
          $this->_results[] = $result;
        }

        /*
        Find next page
        */              
        $url = $this->_baseUrl . '/search?num='.$this->_resultsPerPage.'&q=' . urlencode($this->_searchQuery) . '$start=' . ($currentPage*$this->_resultsPerPage);
      } else {
        throw new Exception('Failed to load page');
      }

      $currentPage++;
    }
  }


  /**
   *  Load the url
   */
  final private function LoadUrl($url)
  {
    if (!is_string($url))
    {
      throw new Exception('Invalid url');      
    }

    $options['http'] = array(
      'user_agent' => "GoogleScraper",
      'timeout' => 0.5
    );
    $context = stream_context_create($options);

    $content = file_get_contents($url, null, $context);
    if (!empty($http_response_header))
    {
      return (substr_count($http_response_header[0], ' 200 OK')>0) ? $content : false;
    }

    return false;    
  }

}
?>
```

Check this [PHP Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/c3n-0ba) to see it in action. Because this could be used quite often from this server, there is a chance for 503 errors from google.

Comment: Thanks Hugo. can I know how many search results can i get by implementing this ?

Comment: It depends on the timeout of your PHP script. You can get 10 results per page and load x amount of pages. So 100 pages is 1000 results. My server loaded them in ~23seconds. If you dont care for the order of the results, you can alter it to load multiple pages at the same time

Comment: in this code only 10 results get fetched and all are repeting 10 times :(

Comment: Damn I missed that, sorry. I have updated it and now it works. I also changed it so it will request 100 results per page (max allowed) so you can load 1000 results in 10 pages now. In the PHP Fiddle you see the results.

Comment: I am getting  E_WARNING : type 2 -- file_get_contents(https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=online+exams) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable -- at line 174
Exception: Failed to load page error

Comment: Did you run it like `$gs = new GoogleScraper('google.com');`? You should either use `$gs = new GoogleScraper();` or `$gs = new GoogleScraper('https://www.google.com');`

Comment: I had just run it in fiddle.

Comment: Strange, fiddle works fine here on several locations, same for my own server. But google has a lot of things in place to prevent scraping, maybe phpfiddle will run on a different server for you (india?) and your server is blocked and mine isn't. Check http://google-scraper.squabbel.com/ to get some info on all of googles security measures. Just rechecked the fiddle for the 100th time and now I do get your error. Seems like some servers are blocked or something. My own server still works. Can you test on your server?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a sleep(1) as cooldown between calls, otherwise might get bebanned.
Did you consider going the official way and getting a google API key?